# Darken Image Slider/Button -- Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage in which users upload an image of some hand written work.  Sometimes it's scanned pencil which can be very difficult to read.

Is it possible to possible to have a slider/button that I could use to darken or maybe even sharpen a particular image?  I would need a slider/button per image as the page I view contains several user uploaded images.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways, one is css filters (see posit labs answer), the other one is with canvas, here is a nice [**tutorial**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/) for that, and here is my [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2h0estfm/6/).

For the demo, you would have to use an image in your own domain (otherwise the canvas becomes tainted and you can't access the pixels), that's why you see the Data URI src in the image, is the only way to make the image origin from the fiddle.

### HTML

```
<img id="myImage" src="mydomain/img.png">

<button class="filter-btn" data-filter="darken" data-img="#myImage">Darken</button>

<button class="filter-btn" data-filter="sharpen" data-img="#myImage">Sharpen</button>
```

If you copy and paste the JavaScript, the only thing you have to do is use this markup for it to work, the image can be configured however you want, the buttons are the important part.

Each button has a `filter-btn` class, to indicate that it's intended to apply a filter, then, you specify the filter via the `data-filter` attribute (in this case it can be sharpen or darken), and finally you link the button to the image via the `data-img` attribute, where you can specify any css selector to get to the image.

### JavaScript

Remember, you don't have to touch any of these if you follow the HTML markup, but if you have any questions about the code, shoot!

```
ImageFilter = {}

ImageFilter.init = function () {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".filter-btn");
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        var btn = buttons[i];
        var filter = btn.dataset.filter;
        var img = btn.dataset.img;
        img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
        (function (filter, img) {
            btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
                ImageFilter.doFilter(filter, img);
            });
        })(filter, img);
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", ImageFilter.init);

ImageFilter.getImage = function (selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
}

ImageFilter.createData = function (canvas, w, h) {
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    return context.createImageData(w, h);
}

ImageFilter.doFilter = function (type, image) {
    var image = ImageFilter.getImage(image);
    switch (type) {
        case "darken":
            var adjustment = -5;
            var canvas = ImageFilter.newCanvas(image);
            var data = ImageFilter.getData(canvas);
            var actualData = data.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < actualData.length; i++) {
                actualData[i] += adjustment;
                actualData[i + 1] += adjustment;
                actualData[i + 2] += adjustment;
            }
            ImageFilter.putData(data, canvas);
            var newImg = image.cloneNode(true);
            newImg.src = ImageFilter.getSource(canvas);
            newImg.id = image.id;
            replaceNode(image, newImg);
            break;
        case "sharpen":
            var weights = [0, -1, 0, -1, 5, -1,
            0, -1, 0];
            var canvas = ImageFilter.newCanvas(image);
            var data = ImageFilter.getData(canvas);
            var side = Math.round(Math.sqrt(weights.length));
            var halfSide = Math.floor(side / 2);
            var src = data.data;
            var sw = data.width;
            var sh = data.height;
            var w = sw;
            var h = sh;
            var output = ImageFilter.createData(canvas, w, h);
            var dst = output.data;
            var alphaFac = 1;
            for (var y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                for (var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                    var sy = y;
                    var sx = x;
                    var dstOff = (y * w + x) * 4;
                    var r = 0,
                        g = 0,
                        b = 0,
                        a = 0;
                    for (var cy = 0; cy < side; cy++) {
                        for (var cx = 0; cx < side; cx++) {
                            var scy = sy + cy - halfSide;
                            var scx = sx + cx - halfSide;
                            if (scy >= 0 && scy < sh && scx >= 0 && scx < sw) {
                                var srcOff = (scy * sw + scx) * 4;
                                var wt = weights[cy * side + cx];
                                r += src[srcOff] * wt;
                                g += src[srcOff + 1] * wt;
                                b += src[srcOff + 2] * wt;
                                a += src[srcOff + 3] * wt;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    dst[dstOff] = r;
                    dst[dstOff + 1] = g;
                    dst[dstOff + 2] = b;
                    dst[dstOff + 3] = a + alphaFac * (255 - a);
                }
            }
            ImageFilter.putData(output, canvas);
            var newImg = image.cloneNode(true);
            newImg.src = ImageFilter.getSource(canvas);
            replaceNode(image, newImg);
            break;
    }
}

ImageFilter.newCanvas = function (image) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    return canvas;
}

ImageFilter.getData = function (canvas) {
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    return context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

ImageFilter.putData = function (data, canvas) {
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
}

ImageFilter.getSource = function (canvas) {
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}

function replaceNode(node1, node2) {
    var parent = node1.parentNode;
    var next = node1.nextSibling;
    if (next) parent.insertBefore(node2, next);
    else parent.appendChild(node2);
    parent.removeChild(node1);
}
```

That's it, see the demo, hope it helps!

### Updates

- **Firefox fix**: creating a new image and replacing the old one each time seems to fix the firefox bug where it doesn't update the image's `src`. (*29/01/15 2:07a.m*)

Comment: Hi Rou.  I'm trying it on FF 35.0.1 and it's not working.  It does work on Chrome though.  Does it work on FF for you?

Comment: @gtilflm It seems like Firefox doesn't want to update the image's `src` when it's Data URI, anyway, a node cloning and replacing fixed it.

Comment: Feel free to ask anything :)

Comment: Ok.  I don't know if this is the place for it.  Maybe the chat would be better.  I've created a room here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69861/rou  If you'd like to join, I'll just hang out there for a while.  If not, then that's ok.

Comment: Hi Rou.  I posted my implementation issue in the chat room.  Please have a look if you're able.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

The easiest way to do this would be with [CSS Filters](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html), but they aren't supported on old browsers ([support table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)). The example below applies a 200% contrast filter.

```
filter: contrast(2);
```

Another option would be to use HTML Canvas to draw the images and manually manipulate the pixels. It's not very fast, and it's much more complicated than CSS Filters. I won't go into depth, but here is an article about [filtering images with canvas](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/).

In my opinion, the users should be responsible for uploading quality images. It seems silly to correct their mistake by adding extra controls to your site.

Comment: @postit labs:  I fully agree with you about the onus being on the users.  The problem is that I'm dealing with kids and there's some quality control issues going on.  I'll check out the CSS filters though.  Thanks.